# linq query grouping and joining getting incorrect sum

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following code which is grouping and summing some values.
The sum "TotalCost" value is correct, however, when i uncomment the lines the sum value is wrong (its less than it should be)

Im doing something wrong, but cant figure this out. any ideas?

```
    from orderItem in Order_ProductItem
    //join ho in Hardware_Items on orderItem.OuterColour equals ho.Index
    //join hi in Hardware_Items on orderItem.InnerColour equals hi.Index
    where orderItem.SalesOrderID == 3272 && (orderItem.IsDeleted==null || orderItem.IsDeleted.Value == false)
    group new { orderItem/*, hi, ho*/} by orderItem.FrameNo into grp
    select new OrderItemModel
    {
    FrameNo = grp.Key,
    TotalCost = grp.Sum(x => x.orderItem.SellingPrice),
    //InternalColor = grp.FirstOrDefault().hi.Name,
    //ExternalColor = grp.FirstOrDefault().ho.Name,
    Quantity = grp.FirstOrDefault().orderItem.Quantity,

    }
```

**Basic Schema**

Order_ProductItem

- FrameNo
- OuterColour
- InnerColour
- SellingPrice

Hardware_Items

- Index
- Name

The Order_ProductItem has FrameNo which is listed multiple times in the table, so im trying to get it to group them, then sum the SellingPrice of each row that has the same FrameNo.

If i exclude the bit to obtain colour (internal and external) the sum is correct.
In that case how can i also include the inner and outer color names?

Comment: Please simplify the example as far as possible (e.g. just have *one* join instead of two) and show us some sample data. Ideally, simplify the schema and query to just the bare minimum required to demonstrate the problem...

Comment: @JonSkeet, I've tried adding more info

Comment: But no data, and no indication of whether just one join is enough to trigger the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a `left join`, because the `inner join` is filtering out some of your data. Here is an example on how you would change your first join.

```
join ho in Hardware_Items on orderItem.OuterColour equals ho.Index into hog
from ho in hog.DefaultIfEmpty()
```